# CRM Plugin to Call External Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-crm-2013

We are on CRM 2013 on premise and we're writing plugin to call external webservice. The webservice is using WSHttpBinding. Basically this plugin will be called during account creation in CRM, then pass information into the webservice.

Here's my code:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
//binding.Security.Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
//binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

var address = new EndpointAddress(ea);

ChannelFactory<IPropertyServiceChannel> factory = new ChannelFactory<IPropertyServiceChannel>(binding, address);
IPropertyServiceChannel channel = factory.CreateChannel();

using (var proxy = new PropertyServiceClient(binding, address))
{
    var tid = new Tid { Dtid = "dMaster", Ptid = "pMain" };

    var newProp = new PropertySetup
    {                  
       //setup data

    };

    proxy.CreateProperty(newProp); //this or below isn't working...
    //channel.CreateProperty(newProp); //this is not working
    //channel.Close();
```

However I keep getting error message:
"The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IPropertyService/CreateProperty' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding."

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Stupid questions, can you reach the service? Via console application are you able to manually create the entity using your service? The authentication is working correctly? You are on prem, so users are probably loggin in via kerberos and win authentication. Do you have IFD in place?

Comment: Yes we do have IFD. I created a simple Console App to just connect to the webservice and it is connecting successfully. However I cannot seem to do so from CRM itself. 
The only thing is we are using Sandbox isolation mode when registering the plugin. Not sure if the webservice call would be working from Sandbox mode? For some reason I keep getting an error trying to register the plugin in 'None' isolation mode even though I'm already a deployment administrator. 
Thanks

Comment: Since it's on Prem as deployment administrator shouldn't complain to register in isolation mode none. From your error I would explore the authentication and the adfs. Also the application pool rights. Seems like when you send the request, instead of authenticating the users is trying to use the crm token and gets angry for that reason.